# ABP 7.0 Blazzor - error 404 Inside my pages when publish

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, abp, abp.io

I create a project with ABP.IO.
I create services, items, DTO ... and also Blazor Page.
All work find on my computer (localhost).

I published my project on a IIS server.
The project lunch normaly i can acces the services all work, the database connection is good.
But i can't load any of my pages, ther is always a 404 error.

[Index.cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlA0q.png)

But the default loggin page work :

[default Account Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZp7e.png)

And the log.txt return me this :

`[16:22:47 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://%2A%2A%2A%2A.fr/InfoPerso - - [16:22:47 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ResolveRequestUri. [16:22:47 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ResolveRequestUri. [16:22:47 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+InferEndpointType. [16:22:47 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ValidateTransportSecurityRequirement. [16:22:47 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ValidateHostHeader. [16:22:47 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://%2A%2A%2A%2A.fr/InfoPerso - - - 302 - - 3.6310ms [16:22:47 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://%2A%2A%2A%2A.fr/Error?httpStatusCode=404 - - [16:22:47 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandlers+ResolveRequestUri. [16:22:47 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ResolveRequestUri. [16:22:47 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers+InferEndpointType. [16:22:47 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ValidateTransportSecurityRequirement. [16:22:47 DBG] The event OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerEvents+ProcessRequestContext was successfully processed by OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandlers+ValidateHostHeader. [16:22:47 INF] Executing endpoint 'Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Theme.Shared.Controllers.ErrorController.Index (Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Theme.Shared)' [16:22:47 INF] Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Error", area = "", page = ""}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] Index(Int32) on controller Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Theme.Shared.Controllers.ErrorController (Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Theme.Shared).
[16:22:47 INF] Executing ViewResult, running view ~/Views/Error/Default.cshtml.`

EDIT :

I remove the line app.UseAbpOpenIddictValidation();
And it works fine exept for the loggin/signup process.
So i think that i miss something whit the parameter of openiddict.
And ma data table is empty.

Is there anything that i should seed to make it work ?
Any tips ?

Comment: The log snippet you provided indicates that your application is encountering a 404 error when trying to access page (/InfoPerso). And it contains 302 redirection.1. Check if there is any specific redirection logic in your application for the /InfoPerso page. 2.Since OpenIddict is involved in processing the request, consider if there are any authentication or authorization conditions that are not met for this specific page when running on IIS, leading to a redirection.3.Check your IIS configuration for any rewrite rules or redirect settings that might be affecting this specific page.

Comment: Not only this page but also all the other are in 404.
and i don't have any rules of redirection, it's like they are not published.